# Word - Populate drop-down with values from table

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to use values from a column in a table in a word document to populate a drop-down?

Example: In a table with the column "Version" there are the following versions:

- 1.1
- 2.5
- 3.5

As such I want to fetch these values and put them in a number of drop-downs. The table does not have a set number of rows, although I can always create a large number of them at first if required. The table is not on the same page as the drop-downs.

Comment: It can be done with VBA. There is nothing in Word (e.g. no property of the dropdown) that lets you "connect" a drop-down to the list of values in a table column without programming.